# VTK: View doesn't update until after user interaction

Tags: c++, vtk

## TL;DR

I have a pipeline which reads an image and displays a mesh using `VTK`; upon changing the input to the image reader and updating the pipeline, the mesh doesn't update until I interact with the window.

## The Long Version

I have a directory with a sequence of segmentation files (i.e., 3D image volumes where pixel values correspond to structures in a corresponding image) which show how a structure changes over time.  I've written a utility in `VTK` which allows me to load the first image in the directory, visualize a label as a mesh, and "step" forwards or backwards using the arrow keys by changing the file name of the input image and updating the pipeline.  This very nearly works--the only issue is that, after updating the pipeline, the meshes don't update until I interact with the window (simply clicking anywhere in the window causes the mesh to update, for example).

## What I've Tried:

1. Calling `Update()` on the reader:

   ```
   this->reader->Update();
   ```
2. Calling `Modified()` on the actors:

   ```
   const auto actors = this->GetCurrentRenderer()->GetActors();
   actors->InitTraversal();
   for (vtkIdType i = 0; i < actors->GetNumberOfItems(); ++i)
     {
     actors->GetNextActor()->Modified();
     }
   ```
3. Calling `Render()` on the current render window:

   ```
   this->GetCurrentRenderer()->Render();
   ```

## MCVE:

NOTE: the reader is updated in `KeyPressInteractorStyle::UpdateReader()`.

```
// VTK
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkNIFTIImageReader.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkCamera.h>
#include <vtkDiscreteMarchingCubes.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h>

// Define interaction style
class KeyPressInteractorStyle : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
{
  public:
    static KeyPressInteractorStyle* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(KeyPressInteractorStyle, vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);

    virtual void OnKeyPress() 
    {
      // Get the keypress
      vtkRenderWindowInteractor *rwi = this->Interactor;
      std::string key = rwi->GetKeySym();

      // Output the key that was pressed
      std::cout << "Pressed " << key << std::endl;

      // Handle an arrow key
      if(key == "Down" || key == "Right")
        {
        this->index += 1;
        this->UpdateReader();
        }

      // Handle an arrow key
      if(key == "Up" || key == "Left")
        {
        this->index -= 1;
        this->UpdateReader();
        }

      // Forward events
      vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnKeyPress();
    }

  void UpdateReader()
    {
    std::cout << "Frame: " << this->index << std::endl;
    const auto fn = this->directory + std::to_string(this->index) + ".nii.gz";
    std::cout << fn << std::endl;
    this->reader->SetFileName( fn.c_str() );
    this->reader->Update();
    const auto actors = this->GetCurrentRenderer()->GetActors();
    actors->InitTraversal();
    for (vtkIdType i = 0; i < actors->GetNumberOfItems(); ++i)
      {
      actors->GetNextActor()->Modified();
      }
    this->GetCurrentRenderer()->Render();
    }
  unsigned int index = 0;
  std::string directory;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkNIFTIImageReader> reader;
};
vtkStandardNewMacro(KeyPressInteractorStyle);

int
main( int argc, char ** argv )
{

  std::string dn = argv[1];

  const auto renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();

  unsigned int frameid = 0;

  const auto reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkNIFTIImageReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName( (dn + std::to_string(frameid) + ".nii.gz").c_str() );

  const auto cubes = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDiscreteMarchingCubes>::New();
  cubes->SetInputConnection( reader->GetOutputPort() );

  cubes->SetValue( 0, 1 );

  const auto mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  mapper->SetInputConnection( cubes->GetOutputPort() );
  mapper->ScalarVisibilityOff();
  const auto actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper( mapper );
  renderer->AddActor( actor );

  const auto window = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
  window->AddRenderer( renderer );
  const auto interactor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();

  const auto style = vtkSmartPointer<KeyPressInteractorStyle>::New();
  style->reader = reader;
  style->directory = dn;
  interactor->SetInteractorStyle( style );
  style->SetCurrentRenderer( renderer );

  interactor->SetRenderWindow( window );

  window->Render();

  interactor->Start();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have actually *not* tried to call `Render()` on the current render window, you are calling it on the current renderer, which are two different things. As the documentation of [vtkRenderer::Renderer()](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderer.html#adc877bbb1ff9a92e36146f7e379815d5) states,

> CALLED BY vtkRenderWindow ONLY.
>
> End-user pass your way and call vtkRenderWindow::Render(). Create an
>   image. This is a superclass method which will in turn call the
>   DeviceRender method of Subclasses of vtkRenderer.

So change `this->GetCurrentRenderer()->Render();` to `this->GetCurrentRenderer()->GetRenderWindow()->Render();`

Comment: This isn't working in my case. Or rather, it works for a few seconds, then stops when Windows decides that the window is unresponsive.